# Scala error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:

Tags: scala

Why am I getting the following error? I thought I am specifying a 
as an Int and also specifying the return value as Int.

```
scala> def adds[A](x: A,y: A)(implicit a:Int = 0 ):Int = a + x + y

<console>:15: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int <and>
  (x: String)String
 cannot be applied to (A)
       def adds[A](x: A,y: A)(implicit a:Int = 0 ):Int = a + x + y
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're effectively specifying `a` as an `Int` and also specifying the return value as `Int`. But it does not compile because the generic type `A` could be a type `MyClass` for example and would not have a method +.

For instance, what do you expect if you do:

```
case class MyClass(a: String)

adds[MyClass](MyClass("a"), MyClass("b"))
```

Comment: What is a bit confusing is the error is talking about overloading and alternatives and not about + missing.

Comment: It said that it can not overload the + method for these types and a type A because, for instance, the method + of Int cannot be applied to a type A.

Comment: Thanks makes sense.